# (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy

I have this error in my apache acces log.

I work with apache 2.2 and tomcat 7. In the access file i see that apache send request to tomcat but tomcat can't treat them all. And when the error occures, i must restart tomcat to make my application work.

I have 2 j2ee applications application on tomcat. That application use connexion to posgres database via jdbc connexion pool. I see in my application log their is at least 4 free connexions. So i don't think there  is trouble with database.

Does someone know what could  cause this error ? Thank you in advence !

Answer (score 5):

Try adding following apache parameters inside `the virtual host section` which should be in `httpd.conf` file or any other place per your server configuration

> ```
> Timeout 2400
> ProxyTimeout 2400
> ProxyBadHeader Ignore
> ```

This resolved problem in my case. I am using Apache 2.4 and tomcat ajp/http configurations.

Comment: `ProxyTimeout` should be what you need. That defaults to the value of `Timeout`, which defaults to 60 seconds. Alternatively, specify on the individual proxy line: `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0 timeout=1200`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your application take more time to respond that apache ProxyTimeout 
[ProxyTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout)
try to increase proxytimeout in you vhost/httpd configuration and try again
The root cause is slowness in you application. you need to find the root cause of slowness

Answer (score 0):

The settings for the packet data transfer needs to be increased which is now low and the ab tool is not able to serve any data after the completion of the mentioned packets.
You can change the configuration as below and then can enjoy running ab tool for your applications.
On Ubuntu Server you can find them in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 32768
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 25
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 8192
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
```